# Losing permissions on hard links when using rsync --delete

Tags: backup, permissions, rsync

Using a cloud based storage medium (Strato's HiDrive product), I employ a backup scheme using `rsync`. During work time, most of my local server files get backed up in the cloud by a cronjob. My backup script makes heavily use of rsync's ability not to copy unchanged files, but to hard link them instead. This looks like

```
rsync -av -M--perms  \
            $inp_sig $REMOTE_USER@$RSYNC_HOST:$REMOTE_BASIS/$CURRENT_SNAPSHOT \
            --exclude-from=$EXCLUDE_FILES \
            --link-dest=$link_destination/
```

where all of the shown variables in advance are set to the correct values by the script. All of this works very well.

During the night, another script gets started that cleans out snapshots that are no longer used. For the deletion task, I use another script which at its heart has the following `rsync` command:

```
empty_dir=`mktemp -d`
rsync -d --delete-before --inplace --perms \
            $empty_dir/  $REMOTE_USER@$RSYNC_HOST:$REMOTE_BASIS/$snap/ || \
                    log_rsync ERROR: could not delete $snap
rm $empty_dir
```

This one works also - almost. Problem is that all permissions on all linked files get squashed by the deleting `rsync` (they all end up with `644` permissions where some of them should have `444`).

I've been tackling the problem for several days now, tinkering with the options of the deleting `rsync` in different combinations. I've tried `-rd` vs. `-r` or `-a`; `--delete` vs. `--delete-before`, to no avail yet. From the manpage I learned that the option `--inplace` should do the trick:

> This option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data
>                 needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating
>                 a new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is
>                 complete, rsync instead writes the updated data directly to
>                 the destination file... Hard links are not broken.

This makes me think that *not* using `--inplace` should result in broken hard links. But in our case, hard links are broken anyway (for the files with differing permission bits).

They also have a `cifs` interface that is perfectly usable for a small number of file operations. But an `rm -rf` on a snapshot directory is by no means feasible - it lasts for hours on a typical backup snapshot, and I have to perform some 16 to 20 deletions per night. The rsync variant runs about two minutes.

So am I lost due to my limited understanding or implied limitations of `rsync`? Or am I just unlucky because of a poor implementation of `rsync` on the provider's side?

Comment: Wow, I just stumbled across the same problem. It doesn't happen often I find bugs in tools like rsync :-)

Answer (score 1):

Problem not completely solved, but worked around.

The problem I described in my post is due to the implementation of `rsync`. I filed a [bug report](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12806) to Bugzilla and got a clear indication that `rsync` indeed does not handle the permission bits correctly when recursively deleting directories.

They pointed out a workaround using the `--super` option:

```
empty_dir=`mktemp -d`
rsync -d --delete --super \
        $empty_dir/  $REMOTE_USER@$RSYNC_HOST:$REMOTE_BASIS/$snap/ || \
                log_rsync ERROR: could not delete $snap
rm $empty_dir
```

Yes, there could be side effects with the `--super` option. For my application, the workaround is sufficient.